# Adding together 4 different Tablix data columns SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have been using

```
 =Sum(Fields!Figure, "Dataset1") 
 + Sum(Fields!Figure, "Dataset2")
```

Now this gives me a result in a text box.

However, i need to sum together the result from 4 different tablix datasets.

I have tried this below but as soon as i try to sum more that 2 datasets it errors.

```
 =Sum(Fields!Figure, "Dataset1") 
 + Sum(Fields!Figure, "Dataset2") 
 + Sum(Fields!Figure, "Dataset3")
 + Sum(Fields!Figure, "Dataset4")
```

This gives me (#error). I am assuming i am missing some code somewhere but i have looked online and cant find anything anywhere.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: my first suggestion would be to test each dataset by adding a text box each only having `=Sum(field!Figure, "Dataset4")` one for each dataset. It might just be that one is incorrectly spelt of the field contains non numeric data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain the field is ended with .value:

```
=SUM(Fields!TextBoxName.Value, "Dataset1")
+SUM(Fields!TextBoxName.Value, "Dataset2")
...
```